# Passing parameters from Detail to MainViewModel in MVVMCross

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have two views : `MainView` and `DetailView`. I have a list of items to display and  when user select an item and I am passing item properties to `DetailViewModel` and user could able to update these values.

Everything works so far, but I wonder how am I passing back to updated values to the `MainViewModel` ?

**MainViewModel.cs**

```
public MainViewModel SelectedItem
{
  get { return _selectedItem; }
  set
  {
    _selectedItem = value;
    ShowViewModel<DetailViewModel>(
    new DetailViewModel.Parameter
    {
        Date = Date,
        Age = _selectedItem.Age,
        Category = _selectedItem.Category,
        Discount = _selectedItem.Discount,
      }
     );

    RaisePropertyChanged(() => SelectedItem);
  }
}
```

**DetailViewModel.cs**

```
public class DetailViewModel: MvxViewModel
{
    public double Age { get; set; }
    public double Category { get; set; }
    public double Discount { get; set; }

    public class Parameter
    {
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public double Age { get; set; }
        public int Category{ get; set; }
        public double Discount { get; set; }
    }

    public void Init(Parameter param)
    {
        Age = param.Age;
        Category = param.Category;
        Discount = param.Discount ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to pass variables between `ViewModels` is a `Messenger` based solution.

MvvmCross Messenger can be found in NuGet.

**MainViewModel**

```
private readonly IMvxMessenger _messenger;
private readonly MvxSubscriptionToken _token;

public MainViewModel(IMvxMessenger messenger) {

    _messenger = messenger;
    _token = messenger.Subscribe<SelectedItemMessage>(OnMessageReceived);;
}

private void OnMessageReceived(SelectedItemMessage obj)
{
    SelectedItem = obj.SelectedItem;
}
```

**DetailViewModel**

```
private readonly IMvxMessenger _messenger;

public DetailViewModel(IMvxMessenger messenger) {
    _messenger = messenger;
}

public void YourUpdateMethod() {
    var message = new SelectedItemMessage(this, SelectedItem); //SelectedItem assumed it is a ViewModel property.
    _messenger.Publish(message, typeof(SelectedItemMessage));
}
```

**SelectedItemMessage**

```
public class SelectedItemMessage : MvxMessage
{
    public SelectedItemMessage(object sender, SelectedItem selectedItem) : base(sender)
    {
        SelectedItem = selectedItem;
    }

    public SelectedItem SelectedItem { get; set; }
}
```

Take a look at http://slodge.blogspot.nl/2013/05/n9-getting-message-n1-days-of-mvvmcross.html for a full guide to `MvvmCross Messenges`.

**Edit using age and category in Message**

```
public SelectedItemMessage(object sender, double age, int category) : base(sender)
    {
        Age = age;
        Category = category;
    }

    public double Age { get; set; }
    public int Category{ get; set; }
}
```

**Changing the MainViewModel OnMessageReceived method**

```
private void OnMessageReceived(SelectedItemMessage obj)
{
    Age = obj.Age;
    Category= obj.Category;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for providing an example. I wonder how you get each item textview to update, for example, `category` or `age` in this approach.

Comment: You could use the `Parameter` object that you created in your post. I'll make an edit.

Comment: The way that I introduced the problem, your message based approach handles very well. I forgot to mention that there is a `SAVE` button in the detailViewModel to save the user entries to confirm. In the current approach, it immediately updates the properties on-the-fly without confirmation. Is there a way to handle that scenerio?

Comment: You could use a second object within `MainViewModel` to save it as temporary data. When the user confirms, transfer the data from your temporary object to your primary object

Comment: Is it possible to illustrate in your example please?

Answer (score 2):

Why not just keep a reference to DetailViewModel when you create it in MainViewModel?  Then any values changed in the DetailViewModel instance will be available via that reference in MainViewModel.

```
private DetailViewModel _detailVM;

public MainViewModel SelectedItem
{
  get { return _selectedItem; }
  set
  {
    _selectedItem = value;
    _detailVM = new DetailViewModel.Parameter {
        Date = Date,
        Age = _selectedItem.Age,
        Category = _selectedItem.Category,
        Discount = _selectedItem.Discount
    };

    ShowViewModel<DetailViewModel>(_detailVM);

    RaisePropertyChanged(() => SelectedItem);
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to illustrate with a simple example, please?

Comment: I think, this will not work, because it's getting serialized.